# Internet Explorer VueJS Issue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, internet-explorer, syntax-error

I'm working on a web application that is working perfectly fine in all web browsers except Internet Explorer, and yes it still has to be maintained for IE unfortunately. I'm getting a syntax error in the web console that I'm not understanding with my VueJS code. Here is an outline of the code that's throwing the error:

```
methods: {
   pageInit: async function() {
      // content
   }
}
```

So specifically on the line with the pageInit function declaration, IE throws the error `Expected '}'`, and I am unsure what the issue with the syntax is. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you use vue-cli to bootstrap the project? Are you using babel or something similar?

Comment: @BrendanBond new to the project and I'm simply maintaining it, but looks like babel is used

Comment: `async/await` syntax is [not supported by versions of IE](https://caniuse.com/?search=async), so you'll need to make sure you're using a polyfill to be able to use this feature. If the project uses Vue-CLI, [make sure you've included the target browser](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/browser-compatibility.html#browserslist) in your `package.json`. If not, [make sure you've included the correct polyfill](https://medium.com/@zwacky/add-es7-async-await-support-into-your-non-bleeding-edge-build-process-ad0dded0d002).

Comment: @BrendanBond Thank you!

Comment: It seems that Brendan Bond’s comment has already mentioned the cause and solution of this problem. Has your problem been solved?